# How to distinguish between a directory and a file

Tags: emacs, elisp

Could anyone please give me an example of how to distinguish between a file and a directory?  `file-readable-p` and `file-exists-p` both return `t` for a valid directory and valid file -- e.g., `/tmp` and `/tmp/foo.txt` yield the same result.

I'd like to write a function that says:

```
(cond
  ( (filename-or-directory is a directory)
    . . . do ABC )
  ( (filename-or-directory is a file)
    . . . do XYZ ) )
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need `file-directory-p`. It returns t for directories.

Comment: `M-x apropos` is your friend.  E.g., `file directory` or `file.*-p`.

Answer (score 1):

If you heavily manipulate files and filepaths, i recommend installing Johan Andersson's [`f.el`](https://github.com/rejeep/f.el) file and directory API with <kbd>M-x</kbd>`package-install`<kbd>RET</kbd>`f`<kbd>RET</kbd>. It has a predicate [`f-directory?`](https://github.com/rejeep/f.el#f-directory-path) that you need and many others.